# Facebook Page Event Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I develop an app that will be available for user which own pages and publish events on it. That app only read data from facebook.

I use the following endpoints :

```
# Get {user-id}
GET /v14.0/me?fields=id,name

# Get {page-id} to get {page-id}
GET /v14.0/{user-id}/accounts

# Get events data according {page-id} 
GET /v14.0/{page-id}/events
```

I can't find any informations about those endpoints limitations. The following [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event) mentions "*Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners*" but doesn't mention the "GET /v14.0/{page-id}/events" endpoint.

Am I concerned about those limitations since I have the owner's access token for pages/events ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: did you test it with a page you own? although, that text tells me for sure that it is not possible

Comment: Thanks for answering me :). My app is not released yet so I tested successfully it with a facebook test user, and straight with the account that own the app. However, I was wondering if in production mode I will have to request for a Facebook Marketing Partners account/grant or not.

Comment: `"GET /v14.0/{page-id}/events"` is accessing events on a page.

Comment: That's not really clear, it says that requirements are "for Events on an App: An App access token of an App that created the Event." or "For Events on a Group:
A User access token of an Admin of the Event. The Groups API feature."
My app is excluded from both of the use cases.